# Comma based string retrieval from database using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am storing the A. SKU_CODE into the doctor details  table as sting with comma based, Now am retrieving the data from the database, Now the case is am getting the value as null, I need to show the data in comma based string.

Is this the right way of inserting the the data into the database or any other better way of inserting the data.

```
 <?php
    include('config.php');
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    $employee_id=$_POST['EMPLOYEE_ID'];
    $sel="SELECT  A.DRSYSCODE,A.DOCTOR_NAME,A.CONVERTED,C.POB_PRODUCT
    FROM DOCTORDETAILS A
    LEFT JOIN POB C ON A.SKU_CODE=C.POB_CODE
    WHERE CREATEDBY=$employee_id";
    $qry=mysql_query($sel);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($qry))
    {
    $select="SELECT D.CREATEDON,B.POB_NAME,B.POBQTY,SUM(D.SOLDQTY)
    FROM DOCTORDETAILS A
    LEFT JOIN U_POB B ON A.DRSYSCODE=B.SYSCODE
    LEFT JOIN POBSOLD D ON A.DRSYSCODE=D.SYSCODE
    WHERE B.POBQTY>0 AND A.DRSYSCODE='".$row['DRSYSCODE']."'";
    $query=mysql_query($select);
    $doctordetails=array();
    $doctordata=array();
    while($quantity=mysql_fetch_array($query)){

    $doctordetails[]=array("POB_NAME"=>$quantity['POB_NAME'],"POBQTY"=>$quantity['POBQTY'],
                    "SOLDQTY"=>$quantity['SOLDQTY'],
                    "CREATEDON"=>$quantity['CREATEDON']);

    }
    $doctordata[]=array("DOCTOR_NAME"=>$row['DOCTOR_NAME'],
                "CONVERTED"=>$row['CONVERTED'],"POB_PRODUCT"=>$row['POB_PRODUCT'],
                "POB"=>array($doctordetails));
    }
    if($doctordata){

            $json = array("status" => 1, 
                          "data"=> $doctordata,
                          "msg" => "Data retrived Successfully");
    } 
    else{
            $json = array("status" => 2, 
                          "msg" => "Data cannot be retrived");
    }
    }
    else{
            $json = array("status" => 0, 
                          "msg" => "Request method not accepted");
    }


    /* Output header */
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($json);
    ?>
```

**POB_PRODUCT is stored in the database**

```
POBDA001,POBDA002,POBDA003,POBDA004,POBDA005,POBDA006,POBDA007,
```

**Obtained Output Response**:

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "DOCTOR_NAME": "TESTING",
            "CONVERTED": "YES",
            "POB_PRODUCT": null,
            "POB": [
                [
                    {
                        "POB_NAME": "TASTE GOOD",
                        "POBQTY": "20",
                        "SOLDQTY": null,
                        "CREATEDON": null
                    }
                ]
            ]
        }
    ],
    "msg": "Data retrived Successfully"
}
```

**Required output:**

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "DOCTOR_NAME": "CHIRANJEEVI",
            "CONVERTED": "YES",
            "POB_PRODUCT": "PROUCT1,PRODUCT2,PRODUCT3",
            "POB": [
                [
                    {
                        "POB_NAME": "TASTE GOOD",
                        "POBQTY": "20",
                        "SOLDQTY": null,
                        "CREATEDON": null
                    }
                ]
            ]
        }
    ],
    "msg": "Data retrived Successfully"
}
```

Comment: No. There's far too much redundant code here. And you're using an ancient, insecure, and deprecated API. Plus, I cannot see an INSERT

Comment: @Sairam Duggi : Can you please try with inner join. I guess problem in  $sel="SELECT  A.DRSYSCODE,A.DOCTOR_NAME,A.CONVERTED,C.POB_PRODUCT
    FROM DOCTORDETAILS A
    LEFT JOIN POB C ON A.SKU_CODE=C.POB_CODE
    WHERE CREATEDBY=$employee_id";